# rearrange date order in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to rearrange the order of my dataframe values under a specific column.

**Data**

```
id  date    stat
aa  Q1.22   5
aa  Q2.22   2
aa  Q3.22   2
aa  Q4.22   1
bb  Q2.22   9
bb  Q3.22   0
bb  Q4.22   0
bb  Q1.22   1
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    stat
aa  Q1.22   5
aa  Q2.22   2
aa  Q3.22   2
aa  Q4.22   1
bb  Q1.22   1
bb  Q2.22   9
bb  Q3.22   0
bb  Q4.22   0
```

**Doing**

```
 df.sort_values(by='date')
```

However, the original dataframe remains, and the dataframe stays unsorted.
Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: use `df=df.sort_values(['id','date'])` instead of sorting values by **'date'** sort by **'id'** and **'date'**

Comment: Right.  The point is that `sort_values` does not sort in place.  It returns a new data frame with that column sorted.

Comment: ok thank you @AnuragDabas - this is not working. I will try and tweak this

Comment: so it is not working?

Comment: no, when I tried on my full dataset, it remains in the same order

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df.sort_values(['id', 'date'])

   id   date  stat
0  aa  Q1.22     5
1  aa  Q2.22     2
2  aa  Q3.22     2
3  aa  Q4.22     1
7  bb  Q1.22     1
4  bb  Q2.22     9
5  bb  Q3.22     0
6  bb  Q4.22     0
```

You have 2 choices:

Return a sorted copy of your dataframe:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'])
```

or sort inplace:

```
df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: I will try again

Answer (score 1):

Another way let's see if it works or not(bcz it's working fine `df.sort_values(['id', 'date'])`):

Idea is to create timestamps from 'date' column then sort values according to them and after sorting drop it:

```
df['sort']=pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'].str.split('.').str[::-1].str.join('-'),freq='Q').to_timestamp()
df=df.sort_values(['id','sort']).drop('sort',1)
```